# NHibernate: single lazy load property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

**Update:** I'm now convinced that the problem lies in the fact that Document is configured as non lazy. The problem is that I don't control the base class and that means I can't change the base props to virtual...

After reading the docs, I'm under the assumption that I should be able to have a non lazy class with a lazy property. Is this possible? Here's the code I'm using for mapping my class:

```
public class DocumentoMapping : ClassMap<Documento> {
public DocumentoMapping()
{
    Setup();
}

private void Setup()
{
    Table("Documentos");
    Not.LazyLoad();
    Id(doc => doc.Id, "IdDocumentos")
        .GeneratedBy.Identity()
        .Default(0);

    Map(doc => doc.NomeDocumento)
        .Not.Nullable();

    Map(doc => doc.Descricao);
    Map(doc => doc.Bytes, "Documento")
        .CustomSqlType("image")
        .CustomType<Byte[]>()
        .LazyLoad()
        .Length(2000000000);

    Component(doc => doc.Acao,
                accao =>
                {
                    accao.Map(a => a.Login);
                    accao.Map(a => a.Data);
                    accao.Map(a => a.UserAD)
                        .CustomSqlType("int")
                        .CustomType<ADs>();
                })
        .Not.LazyLoad();

    Map(doc => doc.IdPedidoAssistencia)
        .Column("IdPats")
        .Not.LazyLoad();
}
}
```

And here's the code for my class:

```
public class Documento : Entity, IHasAssignedId<int>{
public virtual Byte[] Bytes { get; private set; }

public Documento()
{
    NomeDocumento = Descricao = "";
    Acao = new Acao("none", DateTime.Now, ADs.Sranet);
}

public Documento(string nomeDocumento, string descricao, Acao acao)
{
    Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeDocumento));
    Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(descricao));
    Contract.Requires(acao != null);
    Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NomeDocumento));
    Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Descricao));
    Contract.Ensures(Acao != null);
    NomeDocumento = nomeDocumento;
    Descricao = descricao;
    Acao = acao;
}
[DomainSignature]
public String NomeDocumento { get; private set; }
[DomainSignature]
public String Descricao { get; private set; }
[DomainSignature]
public Acao Acao { get; private set; }

internal Int32 IdPedidoAssistencia { get; set; }

internal static Documento CriaNovo(String nomeDocumento, String descricao, Byte[] bytes, Acao acao)
{
    Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeDocumento));
    Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(descricao));
    Contract.Requires(bytes != null);
    Contract.Requires(acao != null);
    var documento = new Documento(nomeDocumento, descricao, acao) { Bytes = bytes };
    return documento;
}

public void ModificaBytes(Byte[] bytes)
{
    Contract.Requires(bytes != null);
    Bytes = bytes;
}

public void SetAssignedIdTo(int assignedId)
{
    Id = assignedId;
}

[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void Invariants()
{
    Contract.Invariant(NomeDocumento != null);
    Contract.Invariant(Descricao != null);
    Contract.Invariant(Acao != null);
}

}
```

Base classes are the just for the basic stuff, ie, setting Id and injecting base code for instance comparison. At first sight, I can't really see anything wrong with this code. I mean, the property is virtual, the mapping says it should be virtual, so why does loading it with Get forces a complete load of the properties? For instance, this code:
     var d = sess.Get(148);

Ends up generating sql for loading all the properties on the table. Did I get this wrong?

thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked if this is still the case, therefore I don't post it as answer, but according to the following source, if you want to have lazy properties on your entity, your entities must also be lazy: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/05/29/nhibernate-pitfalls-lazy-properties-in-non-lazy-entities.aspx

Comment: Yep, that is the case. I've confirmed my assumption yesterday but did not post my conclusions here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's confirmed: in order to have lazy load properties on a class, the class will also need to be lazy.